# Better/shorter way to close database connection in Go

Tags: database, go

Usually I write something like this

```
rows := db.MyPgConn.QueryRows(`SELECT * FROM bla`) // or any other query
for rows.Next() { // if there are result
   // rows.Scan( 
   // do custom operation
}
rows.Close() // close recordset
```

But that way, there are possibility that I forgot to write `rows.Close()` just like this [code](http://golang.org/src/database/sql/sql.go?s=26261:26323#L991) that could make the number of available connection/socket depleted, is there better way to do this?

Comment: From https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#defer "Go's defer statement schedules a function call (the deferred function) to be run immediately before the function executing the defer returns. It's an unusual but effective way to deal with situations such as resources that must be released regardless of which path a function takes to return."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Intermernet, the defer statement is the best way to get the close statement closer to where the rows var is declared. The only way I can think of that might make this shorter or easier would be to create a wrapper function around your database call.

```
func performQuery(q string, op func(db.rows)) {
    rows := db.MyPg.Conn.QueryRows(q)
    // defer rows.Close()
    op(rows)
    rows.Close()
}

// then we could do:
performQuery(`SELECT * FROM bla`,func(rows db.Rows) {
  for rows.Next() {
    // rows.Scan(      
  }
})
```

This however would limit you from making queries with parameters (for example `SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE id = $1`.

Comment: I've used this pattern in Node.js, and it works really well. It can be thought as a form of [destructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor), which is what OP really wants. In Go, `defer` is just a "manual" destructor.

Answer (score 6):

Go introduced [`defer`](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#defer) exactly for this purpose.

```
rows := db.MyPgConn.QueryRows(`SELECT * FROM bla`) // or any other query
defer rows.Close()

for rows.Next() { // if there are result
   // rows.Scan( 
   // do custom operation
}
```

From the documentation:

> Deferring a call to a function such as `Close` has two advantages. First, it guarantees that you will never forget to close the file, a mistake that's easy to make if you later edit the function to add a new return path. Second, it means that the close sits near the open, which is much clearer than placing it at the end of the function.